# Call by need vs call by name

Tags: lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I didn't understand the diffrence between Call-by-name and Call-by-need. As I understood, Call-by-need method restores the answer returned. But how It helps us, and Is there any fundamental difference between the results ?

For example,

```
begin integer n;
  procedure foo(e, n);
  integer e, n;
  begin
    for n := 1 step 1 until 10 do begin
      prints(`;;; the value of e is ');
      printnln(e)
    end
  end;
  foo(2 * n, n)
end
```

So in call-by-name, as I understood, We will get:

```
;;; the value of e is 2
;;; the value of e is 4
;;; the value of e is 8
```

and so on. This is because we pass `2*n` to `e`, and `e` is evaluate with the new `i` everytime.
What would happen in call-by-need?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In call by need, we enter the loop, and evaluate the value only once. So In the code above, we will copy `(2*n)` inside the loop (macro-style) and we will evaluate the expression only one time (Not like call by name). 
So, in the first iteration we will get `e=2`. this will be the value of `e` also in the next iteration, and the output will be:

```
;;; the value of e is 2
;;; the value of e is 2
;;; the value of e is 2
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems that your confusion stems from the fact that you are thinking in an [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) context. The discussion of *call-by-need* vs. *call-by-value* mostly comes up about declarative and functional languages, and lambda calculus.

You can see in this article about [evaluation strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) that both *call-by-name* and *call-by-need* are considered *lazy evaluation* strategies. Lazy evaluation means that when an expression is passed as a parameter to a function, it is not evaluated before entering the function body, but only when it is accessed/read the first time inside the function. If the result of such expression is never used inside, then it will never be evaluated.

For example the `? :` operator is lazy in Java as the below code demonstrates:

```java
String test(Object obj)
{
    return 1 == 2 ? obj.toString() : "Hello World";
}

test(null); // this won't throw a NullPointerException
```

*Call-by-need* is an essential feature of most functional languages which have a *pure* subset. In a [purely functional language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_functional_language), every function has to be [referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29), i.e. they cannot have [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). Such [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) have the property that for some given input they always return the same output, no matter how many times called, and that they never change anything in the "state of the world". They behave just like mathematical functions written on the paper.

As you have already realized, *call-by-need* strategy is not feasible when calling non-pure functions, because you are most probably interested in the side-effects due to the consecutive calls. On the other hand it becomes an essential feature for performance when used in purely functional languages (see the second example below). Also, see these wiki pages about the concepts of [Graph Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_reduction) and [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

#### Real-world examples

**First.** One example of a commonly used system which uses graph reduction is [Apache Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant). Ant does not evaluate a target twice. This design makes it convenient to sketch up a declarative build plan.

**Second.** If you want to see a good demonstration of memoization, type this [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) code to a [GHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) interpreter and see what happens:

```hs
Prelude> let fibs = 0:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
-- This defines the Fibonacci sequence.
Prelude> fibs !! 200000
-- Prints the 200,000th Fibonacci number,
-- takes several seconds to calculate.
Prelude> fibs !! 200000
-- Prints the same number as before,
-- but this time it returns immediately.
```

---

**Note.** You might also have heard about the *call-by-value* evaluation strategy. In contrast with *call-by-name* and *call-by-need*, *call-by-value* is a strict evaluation strategy. It is like *call-by-name* in the sense that calling multiple times result in multiple evaluation. This is the most common paradigm for programmers who are accustomed to imperative languages like  C# or Java.

Answer (score 9):

Call-by-name is a function calling discipline where when a call is made to a receving function foo, instead of the arguments to foo being evaluated, foo receives (behind the scenes) an appropriate object that will allow it to evaluate the parameters it needs; or equivalently, evaluation progresses by macro substitution. If a parameter is required more than once, it will be evaluated more than once. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name

Call-by-need is much the same, except that the object passed is a *promise*, and will be evaluated no more than once; on subsequent references to a parameter, the memoised value is used. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_need

Answer (score 5):

First of all, either call-by-need or call-by-name represent ways of implementing lazy-evaluation, so it necessary to know what is [lazy-evaluation](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementing-laziness/) ...

You can see call-by-need in Haskell for example and call-by-name in Scala.

**call-by-need** is maybe the expected way of implementing laziness. The first time you "really" need the value, you computed it and you make a cache of the computed value for future access.

when you have **call-by-name** you don't perform this sort of caching, you evaluate the function arguments every time they are used in the function body. It is possible to think that it does not have sense, but it is useful to implement some flow control structure as function of the language, let say a while.

```
def myWhile (cond : => Boolean, body : => Unit) {
  if (cond) { body ; myWhile (cond, body) }
}
```

And then you can call the function myWhile,

```
var x = 3

myWhile (x != 0, {
  print (x)
  x = x - 1   
})
```

If we had call-by-name for the example above, the expression "cond" is not cached and it is evaluated each time is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both call by name and call by need is like macro expansion.But in call by need once the value is evaluated it memoized the value and use this value next time.
for eg:-there is a question in gate 2003.

```
global int i=100,j=5;
void P(x){
    int i=10;
    printf("%d",x+10);
    i=200;
    j=20;
    printf("%d",x);}

main(){P(i+j);}
```

CALL BY NAME:
in place of x in function it becomes i+j *so first print will be i+j+10=10+5+10=25* and *next print will be i+j=200+20*
  **output:25,220**

CALL BY NEED:
in place of x it becomes i+j and after first print ,x i.e. i+j value becomes 15 it memoized it.
so output will be
**output:25,15**